# how to access nested elements using ContentChildren in angular

Tags: angular

I have the following code snippet

```
<my-tabs>
   <my-tab>
       <tab-heading>Users</tab-heading>
       <tab-content>Users Data</tab-content>
   </my-tab>
   <my-tab my-tab--active>
       <tab-heading>Groups</tab-heading>
       <tab-content>Roles Data</tab-content>
   </my-tab>
</my-tabs>
```

I want to access all the `tab-heading` so I am using `@ContentChildren` decorator like this

```
@ContentChildren(TabHeading, { descendants: true })
    tabHeadingList: QueryList<TabHeading>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.tabHeadingList);
}
```

but this returns the empty list. Is it possible to get the same using `@ContentChildren` or any other way around?

Here is `TabHeading` Class

```
@Component({
    selector: "tab-heading",
    template: `<li class="tab"><a href="#123456789"><ng-content></ng-content></a></li>`
})
export class TabHeading {
}
```

Even I tried with `ngAfterContentInit` hook still not working.

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log("Content Init");
    console.log(this.tabHeadingList);
}
```

I am able to get `my-tab` though. but not able to get the nested child.

Comment: `tab-heading` looks like a custom component. I think you have to use the name of the actual component you are using, so maybe `@ContentChildren(TabHeading,` should be `@ContentChildren(TabHeadingComponent,` or whatever the components name is that you declared it as

Comment: `ContentChildren` won't have their values resolved until the `ngAfterContentInit` lifecycle hook. They won't be there in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: @joh04667 tried with ngAfterContentInit, but still empty array

Comment: @rhavelka , Component name is `TabHeading`

Comment: may it is not QueryList try use any and see if you get values then set the correct type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TabHeading` is my custom angular component, I was not registering it to `ngmodule`.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [MyTab, MyTabs, TabHeading],
    exports: [MyTab, MyTabs, TabHeading]
})
export class TabsModule { }
```

Comment: while debugging always look for the console errors first.

Comment: there was no error on the console, otherwise no need to put this question on So